# SAS CAS apply group by function (Pyspark)

Tags: group-by, sas, user-defined-functions, casl

Is it possible to run a casl function and apply it with a groupby function?

I used to apply rely on this type of pyspark coding approch:

```
df.groupby("key").apply(g)
```

where g is a function that is appy on the groupby subset in a distribuite way.
It may cointein a function that e.g. return for each "key" subsample alpha e beta of a univariate linear regression.

```
Proc reg data=df;
by key;
...
run;
```

does not work in a distribuite but run 1 regression at time.

Answer (score 0):

CAS automatically distributes functions. CAS-enabled PROCs, the DATA Step, FEDSQL, and all CAS actions are distributed and multithreaded. For example, consider the following dataset in CAS:

```
data casuser.foo;
    set casuser.bar;
    by group1 group2;

    newvar = round(var);
run;
```

CAS will do the following:

1. Distribute the data by `group1` among the servers and threads
2. Order data by `group2`
3. Process the data step code

When you run the data step in CAS, you'll see this in the log:

```
NOTE: Running DATA step in Cloud Analytic Services.
NOTE: The DATA step will run in multiple threads.
```

A similar thing occurs with [CAS-enabled PROCs](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2021/11/22/cas-enabled-procedure.html). It will automatically be distributed on data that is loaded to CAS. For example, use `proc regselect` to run a distributed regression in CAS:

```
cas;
libname casuser cas caslib='casuser';

data casuser.cars;
    set sashelp.cars;
run;

proc regselect data=casuser.cars;
    by origin;
    class drivetrain;
    model horsepower = enginesize cylinders mpg_city mpg_highway drivetrain;
run;
```

FEDSQL is also distributed:

```
proc fedsql sessref=casauto;
    create table casuser.foo as
        select origin
             , mean(horsepower) as mean_horsepower
        from casuser.cars
        group by origin
    ;
quit;
```

[Many traditional SAS PROCs are CAS-enabled as well](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_037/proc/p0nnkdmqmz48w8n1kqofzc7mcla4.htm), such as PROC MEANS:

```
proc means data=casuser.cars noprint;
    by origin drivetrain;
    var horsepower;
    output out=casuser.foo 
        mean(horsepower) = mean_horsepower
    ;
run;
```

In the log you'll see that the [aggregation.aggregate CAS action](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_037/casanpg/cas-aggregation-aggregate.htm) does most of the heavy lifting:

```
NOTE: The CAS aggregation.aggregate action will be used to perform the initial summarization.
```